# Generate XML schema from database table in Java

Tags: database, xsd

I am new here and heard i can find good answers here so i signed up and now i write about my problem.
Do you have any idea about java class library or anything useful that can generate XML SCHEMA from a table in database like sql server in java?
I am new to java so i need some basic guidlines if possible.
Regards,
Sherry

Answer (score 0):

Tables are relational; XML is hierarchical.  It's not a trivial task.

XML requires a single root.  What will yours be?

You'll need to extract table definitions.  I'd guess that tables/entities would be parent tags, columns would be child tags, with values as child data.  You'd have to figure out from foreign key relationships how to nest parents.  And if there are many-to-many JOIN tables, you'll have to decide which will be the master and which the slave.  You have to break the circular relationship.

You'll have to make decisions about types in your .xsd.

You can map relational tables to Java objects using an ORM tool like Hibernate.  You can map Java objects to XML and back using JAX-B.  Transitivity would tell you that relational to XML is possible, but I don't know of a simple, direct path between the two.